# PHP header location redirect going to http instead of https

Tags: php, redirect

I am on aws lightsail for a dev server and beanstalk for a live server.  Lightsail has php 7.3 and beanstalk has 7.4.

I created a link that is then read in php and does a

```
header('Location: /i/'.$res[0]['code'])
```

based on the url passed in.

The initial link is like https://test.example.com/c/12ksskdad

The link has a slightly different domain on the production beanstalk server and uses a different ssl cert.

If I redirect the link from the lightsail server, it redirects to https://test.example.com/i/adfadf which is correct.
if I redirect from the production beanstalk server, for certain browsers, especially iphone browsers, it redirects to http://test.example.com/i/adfadf.

It redirects to http, instead of https.  I should be able to use the full url path to correct this, but we run from different urls and I don't want to do that if I don't have to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that you are on https $_SERVER["HTTPS"] and you can use $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] to pass actual server name without hard coding it:

```
header('Location: '. $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/i/'.$res[0]['code']);
```

Comment: This is what I will probably end up doing.  It is always going to be https so I don;t even need that check.  I am in the middle of a lot of changes and did not want to have to do a code push.  Was hoping it was some php setting.

Comment: They actually updated the load balancer to always serve https, which is working fine.  I made the update that you recommended as well.   Thanks for the answer.